# How do I make a divider/hr that is purely for decoration?

Tags: html, css, line, divider

I wan to make a horizontal line to specify where a user should look to find corresponding information on the other side of a table. Does anyone know how to do this without just having to type in "----"s?

Like these horizontal lines 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuPwN.png)

Or basically, how would I do the above image example at all?

Answer (score 0):

How I would do this:

You have a ul > li list for instance.

The li has a grey background color.
The spans also have a grey background color, and a position relative with a z-index of 2.

Then we need an :after on the li, with a dashed border at the bottom.

Ez pz right?

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Chapter 1</span>
        <span class="page">1.0</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul, li {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
li {
    position:relative;
    background-color:grey;
}
li span {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    float:left;
    background-color:grey;
}
li span.page {
    float:right;
}
li:after {
    border-bottom:1px dashed black;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:0;
    height:1px;
    z-index:1;
    content:'';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But can you be more specific? Like words from my image example? (Sorry, I am new and learning)

Comment: @Hannah i provided some untested dummy code, but it should work like that

Comment: You might need to add styles like height and width on `li` and `spans` but you will figure it out ;)

Comment: The dashed line doesn't show up for me (using chrome).

Comment: Ooh yes add `content:'';` on the :after